# I erased haproxy.log with old content but this file hasn't appeared again

Tags: logging, haproxy, rsyslog

I have a load balancer with HAProxy in Ubuntu 14.04. I did all configurations for turn on log and it works well. However, I erased haproxy.log file and that hasn't appeared again. Can someone help me?

I restart rsyslog and haproxy service. But it didn't work! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have sure that your configurations files is right, make the file yourself, but make sure to give permissions to syslog user.

```
chown syslog:adm /var/log/haproxy.log
```

This should do the trick. Make sure to restart both rsyslog and haproxy.

Comment: It does the trick. Do you know of any way to empty the HAProxy file without the need to restart?

Answer (score 0):

Please restart haproxy to create new file.

For erasing haproxy use this command
Echo > /haproxy log location

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting the server did it. Restarting the haproxy service was not enough